# SQL To get Distinct Name and Number from table

Tags: sql

Looking for sql to get distinct names and count of those names from a sql table:

Structure:

```
id
name
other details
```

Do I use distinct to get each group and then count through those to get:

```
name1 count(name1)
name2 count(name2)
etc
```

Thanks
Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 3):

When you want a COUNT() or a SUM(), you're using an AGGREGATE FUNCTION based on a GROUP BY clause.

As GROUP BY brings together all records with the same values specified in the GROUP BY columns, you're already getting the same effect as DISTINCT.

Except that DISTINCT doesn't allow aggregates, and GROUP BY does.

```
SELECT
  name,
  COUNT(*) AS count_of_name
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  name
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select name,COUNT(name) FROM Persons GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `school`,COUNT(`school`) AS cat_num FROM table GROUP BY school order by cat_num DESC
```